# How to update multiple outputs simultaneously

Tags: digital, timing, port-mapping, assembly

I need to update simultaneously all the outputs of a specific port.

I am familiar with using micro-processors assembly language. After initializing a port (Data Direction Register), I can write to that port and all outputs will update simultaneously.

In the Arduino commands  : I am aware of how to configure pins, such as pinMode(pin, mode), to make a pin an output or input.

I know of the digitalWrite(pin, value) , but this only updates one pin per command.

For timing reasons, I need to update several (same port) outputs without any time delay.

Normally (using assembly language) , I would keep a register with the data I desire on the output port, and write that register's data to the port.

Is there a command I can use in Arduino to accomplish the same thing?
If not a single command, what other choices do I have?

I use Arduino  micro,  UNO,  but I think the question might be valid for most Arduino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the ports of an Uno are addressed in C/C++ as PORTB, PORTC, and PORTD respectively, each 8 bits wide. You can read them or assign to them. Other processors' ports have similar names. Of course the pins' port assignments and functions differ from one to the other, which is one reason for providing the single-pin pinMode() and digitalRead(), digitalWrite() functions. But where you need to deal directly with the hardware (and probably don't care about chip-to-chip portability), the registers are exposed with the above symbols.

Also note that most other CPU registers are exposed the same way - the ports' data-direction registers as DDRA, DDRB, DDRC. You may not care about setting them up simultaneously, but if you wanted to make all of your hardware accesses similarly (and save the flash space for the portable pin functions), you could.

Update:

> Is there a specific command I can use ? Such as Write PortD ?

Yes, you can use the PORTx names like any other C/C++ variable:
`PORTD = 0xFF;`
`PORTD ^= 0x02;`
`if( (PORTD & 0x40) != 0 ){`
, for just a couple of examples - just like real C! :-)

PS: [Pighixxx](http://www.pighixxx.com/test/) makes absolutely top-notch pinout diagrams for boards & processors. Here is his diagram for the [28-pin DIP-packaged AtMega328p](http://www.pighixxx.com/test/portfolio-items/atmega328/?portfolioID=337) for instance. They're extremely useful when you're working with a chip at the port or board level.

Comment: Is there a specific command I can use ?   Such as Write PortD  ?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do more than 8 (especially LOTS more), and timing is very critical, you can use a Serial In, Parallel Out (SIPO) chip, such as the 74HC595 - it also saves a lot of pins on the Arduino.

To use it, you need 3 pins connected to the Arduino. You send one bit to the chip from the Arduino for each output, then when you have them all set, you toggle the Latch pin - all output pins change at the same time. The chip has 8 outputs.

Another advantage of a chip like this is that you can daisy-chain them - with the same 3 pins, you can control as many pins as you like (subject to power availability, of course!).

Read https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut for more information on how to use them. They are dirt cheap (about US$1.26 each if you buy 10 from AliExpress, shipped to NZ, which is where I am).

Comment: Even though I selected another answer as more directly answering my question, your answer is also very helpful.